# Using concepts to enable member functions when the template parameter is a specific templated class

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

The aim is to enable a member function when the template parameter of the class is a specific templated class `Ptr <U>`. The following code does actually work but it requires the template parameter `U` to be repeated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T> class Ptr
{
public:
};

template <typename T, typename U> concept is_a_Ptr = std::is_same <T, Ptr <U>>::value == true;

template <class T> class Container
{
public:
  void PlainFoo () {};
  template <class U> void OptionalFoo () requires is_a_Ptr <T,U> {};
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Container <Ptr <int>> foo;
  foo.OptionalFoo <int> (); // Requires <int> to be specified
  // foo.OptionalFoo (); // Would like to be able to do this
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to avoid having to specify the `int` ? I know it can be implemented with specialization but that requires a fair amount of code refactoring so I'm hoping not to have to do that.

Comment: You really shouldn't want to. Whatever properties that `Ptr` provides may well be provided by some other type. Indeed, the whole point of concepts is to check for the properties of interest themselves, *not* specific class types or template instantiations.

Comment: Point taken and in fact I will need it to apply to other classes. In reality (and simplifying a bit) I have a set of classes Ptr1<>, Ptr2<>,... which could all derive from a Ptr_Base<>. That's the next step. I didn't want to go down that route without getting a simpler example to work first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid having to specify the `int`?

I would recommend to add a type alias in `Ptr` which would look like this:

```
template <class T> class Ptr
{
public:
    using type = T;
};
```

And then you could default the type parameter of `OptionalFoo()`:

```
template <class U = typename T::type> 
void OptionalFoo () requires is_a_Ptr <T,U> {};
```

This way you will not have to specify the type again and you can just call it as:

```
Container <Ptr <int>> foo;
foo.OptionalFoo (); // identical to foo.OptionalFoo<int>();
```